# Create and attach Confluence page using python

Tags: python, jira

```
import requests
import json
import base64

# Define API endpoint and authentication details
base_url = "https://bhush.atlassian.net/wiki"
api_url = f"{base_url}/rest/api/content"
username = "bhushl@gmail.com"
password = "ATATT3xFfGF01VT_Nb2OaGoyBQNki9-l8jrdBuqyAQHuNKvENzmntWJVbdmKOGiZLcjGm444QX_j_zcWutBNh5P1Tv3kpbdqmwhZxM-R88JQOryz_rp0k1FPl6FltSsi52_flvtTbWmam0N6L8cFLVVdK3mcElqDSMrSXeB5DAXs=1C3C5356"

# Define page title and parent page ID
page_title = "Example Page8"
parent_id = "262234"

# Define headers and payload for creating page
headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
}
payload = {
    "type": "page",
    "title": page_title,
    "ancestors": [{"id": parent_id}],
    "space": {"key": "automation"},
    "body": {
        "storage": {
            "value": "<p>This is an example page.</p>",
            "representation": "storage"
        }
    }
}

# Make API call to create page
response = requests.post(
    api_url,
    auth=(username, password),
    headers=headers,
    json=payload
)

# Check response status code and get new page ID
if response.status_code == 200:
    page_id = response.json()["id"]
    print(f"Page created successfully! ID: {page_id}")
else:
    print("Error creating page:", response.status_code, response.text)
    exit()

# Define file path and name
file_path = "test.docx"
file_name = "test.docx"

# Open file and read contents
with open(file_path, "rb") as f:
    file_contents = f.read()

# Define headers and payload for attaching file
headers = {
    "X-Atlassian-Token": "nocheck"
}
payload = {
    "file": (file_name, file_contents)
}

# Make API call to attach file to page
attach_url = f"{api_url}/{page_id}/child/attachment"
response = requests.post(
    attach_url,
    auth=(username, password),
    headers=headers,
    files=payload
)

# Check response status code for file attachment
if response.status_code == 200:
    print("File attached successfully!")
else:
    print("Error attaching file:", response.status_code, response.text)
```

This is the code. I am unable to create the page and attachment.
I am using confluence REST API with python.
This script is not creating new page and adding attachment.
I tried several different ways, please advice any workaround.

Infosys' net profit missed analyst estimates. The company also expects lower sales in the future. The stock hit 52-week low today.

Other sectors (financial services, media, pharma) ended only 0.1-0.6% down.

PSU banks gained the most, up 3.13%.